# Inverse vs Invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, they talk about a matrix being an inverse and a matrix being invertible. Is there a difference because they seem like the same thing, but when I reading about them, sometimes they seem like there related, but different. So is their a difference? Or can the words inverse and invertible be used interchangeably?

Comment: An invertible matrix is one that has an inverse. The inverse itself is a matrix. Note that *invertible* is an adjective, while *inverse* (in this sense) is a noun, so they clearly cannot be synonymous.

Comment: Think of the difference between "having a brother" and "being a brother".

Comment: @EthanBolker A word of caution about your analogy. If a matrix $A$ has an inverse $B$, then $A$ also is an inverse (namely the inverse of $B$). On the other hand, it is possible to have a brother without being a brother (namely by being female).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Right thanks. It's just an analogy, and caution is wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, *inverse* is a noun and *invertible* is an adjective. If a matrix is *invertible*, then it has an *inverse*. Here's the definition of an inverse:

**Definition** A matrix $B$ is said to be the *inverse* of a matrix $A$ if and only if $$AB = BA = I,$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. In this case, we write $B = A^{-1}$. When the matrix $B = A^{-1}$ exists, we say that $A$ is *invertible.*

Is this clear enough? I will be happy to clarify anything in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse and Invertible does not mean the same.

Matrix $A_{n*n}$ is Invertible when is non-singular or regular, this is:

$\det(A) \neq 0$ and $rank(A) = n$

This means that each column of $A$ is not a linear combination of the rest, so A has full-rank and non-zero determinant, therefore it's regular or non-singular and is invertible as a consequence.

Obviously a matrix has inverse when it is invertible. So if the previous properties don't hold then the matrix $A$ doesn't have an inverse.

Inverse matrices satisfy above conditions and $A\cdot A^{-1} = A^{-1}\cdot A = I$ but this is only true when $A$ is a square matrix.

For non-square matrices we may have right or left inverses see [inverse element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#Matrices) for more info about these.